# PDFSharp Insert an image in a pdf using a PdfTextField as the position and size reference

Tags: c#, image, pdf, pdfsharp

We want to insert a png image with a (drawn)signature into a PDF with PDFSharp. The position and size of the image is determined by a invisible PdfTextField that we created previously in the PDF. With our current code the problem is: How can we get the page reference from our PdfTextField (the page that contains this field)?

Code:

```
PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open("C:\\filex.pdf", PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify);

// Get the root object of all interactive form fields
PdfAcroForm form = document.AcroForm;

// Get all form fields of the whole document
PdfAcroField.PdfAcroFieldCollection fields = form.Fields;

//Get the invisible PdfTextField used as position and size reference
PdfTextField signatureposition= (PdfTextField)fields["thesignature"];

PdfArray signaturerect= (PdfArray)signatureposition.Elements["/Rect"];
string x = signaturerect.Elements[0].ToString();
string y = signaturerect.Elements[1].ToString();
string w = signaturerect.Elements[2].ToString();
string h = signaturerect.Elements[3].ToString();

string imagepath= "C:\\signature.png";

//how to get the correct page reference respect the especified field?
PdfPage page= signatureposition.Owner.Pages[???];

XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
XImage image = XImage.FromFile(imagepath);
gfx.DrawImage(image, x, y, width, height);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end we solved it creating this function:

```
   protected int PaginaCampo(string campofirma, PdfDocument document)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < document.Pages.Count; i++)
    {
        PdfAnnotations anotations = document.Pages[i].Annotations;
        for (int j = 0; j < anotations.Count; j++)
        {
            if (anotations[j].Title != campofirma) continue;
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Not the best solution but it works...if someone adds a better one we will give the correct answer to him/her

Comment: What does campofirma represent?  Is it the string the png of the firma (signature?)

Comment: @RaySuelzer: compofirma in this case looks to be the title of the page.  The signature was being placed with the gfx.drawimage.   OP was just trying to figure out which page number to place the image on.